# Tamanho de texto em div

Tags: html, css3

Tenho um texto dentro de uma div e o mesmo não vai até o fim da mesma e gostaria que isso acontecesse, o texto é o que está posicionado a direita da página ao lado da imagem maior.
Criei uma div genérica para fazer alguns testes.

A div com sua configuração original:

```
.one-fourth {
    width: 20.5%;   
    max-width: 220px;
}
```

Fiz os cálculos, mas não consegui.

A div com a minha alteração

```
.one-fourth-pers {
    width: 40.5%;   
    max-width: 220px;
}
```

```
.column-last { 
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

O  site em questão é esse:
[Página de detalhes do produto](http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/detalhes.php?produto=90&dep=1&subdep=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente realizar a seguinte alteração na classe .one-fourth removendo o max-width.

```
.one-fourth-pers {
    width: 40.5%;
    /* max-width: 220px; */
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Olá @user2363, agora o texto está em uma linha mas o mesmo ficou abaixo da imagem, veja: http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/detalhes.php?produto=432&dep=3&subdep=34

Comment: você esqueceu de adicionar um floar left a classe .one-fourth-pers

Comment: Obrigado, @user2363, tenho sofrido muito com esse layout responsivo, agradeço a ajuda, ficou excelente o resultado.

Comment: caso você tenha interrese, você dá uma olhada na implementação do Zurb Foundation. pode lhe ajudar a entender melhor o funcionamento de um layout responsivo. http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: Claro, tenho interesse sim e obrigado novamente pela excelente dica.